# How to make horizontally expanding Control next to fixed-width Control in SWT

Tags: eclipse, layout, swt, eclipse-rcp

I would like to accomplish the following:

[image: horizontal expansion]

Where one fixed-width control is adjacent to a horizontally-expanding control that fills the available space.

I am already able to use `GridLayout` to accomplish this **vertically**:

[image: vertical expansion]

by using the following code:

```
parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Button button1 = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
button1.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.BEGINNING, true, false));
button1.setText("First");

Button button2 = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
button2.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));
button2.setText("Second");
```

Is there a way to do the horizontal version without having to explicitly specify the number of columns? Other GUI toolkits (e.g. Android, QT, and GTK) do facilitate such a thing.

Currently my horizontal solution is this:

```
parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

Button button1 = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
button1.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.BEGINNING, GridData.FILL, false, true));
button1.setText("First");

Button button2 = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
button2.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));
button2.setText("Second");
```

Comment: Use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) instead, it will solve a huge amount of layout problems for you ;]..

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify the number of columns in `GridLayout`. I don't understand why that should be a problem (and what you have seems to work). You can compute the number of columns as necessary depending on how many widgets you have.

[This SWT Layout article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) is quite good. If you want to control the size of your first object, specify a `widthHint` in the `GridData`.

Comment: It is not a "problem" to specify the number of columns, but it _is_ redundant. Ideally there would exist an uncomplicated `Layout` class that allows horizontal expansion of designated elements.

Comment: Actually it's not redundant as there has to be some means of telling the layout the position on the grid, and for the `GridLayout` that's the means. There are many layout managers and some much simpler, but much less capable. For me, I have found it good to learn someting like `GridLayout` well and use it for everything, as it's quite flexible and powerful, rather than learning 5 different layout managers for different purposes.

Comment: In Android there is `LinearLayout`, and in GTK+ there is `HBox`. Ideally the (horizontal) `RowLayout` class in SWT would allow for the expansion of designated elements, but it seems that only `GridLayout` supports designated expansion. I'm forced to use `GridLayout` and to explicitly specify the number of columns, even though no grid functionality is desired. I don't want to have to tell it the position on the _grid_ -- I just want a single row. With linear layout classes of other toolkits, the number of columns is inferred by the number of children added to the layout.

Comment: Well the fundamental problem here is that SWT does not provide a good enough single row layout manager (and other technologies do) And in any multi-row layout manager you need a means to say when the row break happens. `GridLayout` chose number of columns which is reasonable for what it does.